# Boolean function equivalent

Tags: boolean-algebra

The following  Boolean function equivalent to.
F(A,B,C,D) = PI(1,3,5,7,13,15)

a)BD' + ACD'
b)BD'+ACD+ABC'D
c)(B+D')(A+C+D')
d)(A+D')(B'+D')

I wrote down the truth table for 4 input. I tries simplifying the SOP expression but it is not matching with any of the options.

Comment: Try drawing K-map

Comment: Should I find SOP or POS?

Comment: POS, as you have $\Pi$

Answer (score 0):

There is no match. You are right.

I am first looking at the input combinations which are not dependent on the order of inputs:

If all four inputs are `true` (= minterm 15), expressions `a)` and `d)` return `false` and are thus ruled-out.

All inputs `false` (= minterm 0) is not part of the expression but is covered by `c)`. Therefore, it can't be `c)`

The numbering of minterms $0..15$ depends on the column order of the input variables in the truth table. Usually, the left-most input has the highest weight and the right-most variable the lowest weight.

Assuming variable weights of `A=8`, `B=4`, `C=2` and `D=1`:
Term `BD'` covers minterms $1,3,9,11$ which are not all part of the expression

Variable weights `A=1`, `B=2`, `C=4` and `D=8`:
Term `BD'` now covers minterms $2,3,6,7$ which are also not completely covered by the expression.